# Contour Design Unimouse Button Not Recognized on Linux (xev, xinput ,evtest)

Tags: mouse, hardware, input-devices

I use the Contour Design Unimouse on my Linux setup (Ubuntu) and I am encountering an issue. While most of the mouse's functions work as expected, the middle button (which is not the scroll button, but an additional third button)  doesn't seem to be recognized by the system. I've tried various diagnostic tools such as xev, xinput, and evtest, but none of them register an event when this button is pressed.

Has anyone else experienced a similar issue with the Contour Design products on Linux? I would just like to configure the particular button to function as a double click button, like I had on Windows.

Any advice or experiences shared would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Always read the manual I guess. This works, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The manual says

> Middle Click to Double Click Unimouse comes with middle click as the default setting. To change the middle click function to double click, hold down the cursor speed button and the middle click at the same time. To switch back, repeat the same command."